# Getting Exception in thread "main"java.lang.Error

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

CODE:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class SelIntroduction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Invoking Browser
        //Chrome - ChromeDriver -> Methods
        //Chromedriver.exe -> invokes chrome browser//it is a third party library provided by chrome
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\Users\91888\Downloads\chromedriver_win32.exe");
        //webdriver.chrome.driver->value of the path 
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
}
```

CONSOLE:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  "  '  \ )

```
at SelIntroduction.main(SelIntroduction.java:12)
```

Chrome browser should launch but ended up with an Exception

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an exception, this is the Eclipse compiler creating a class file for you so you can keep working even though your code wouldn't actually compile with the JDK. Like the message says, you have an invalid escape sequence on line 12. If you're going to specify Windows paths with the backslashes, the backslashes themselves have to be escaped--with additional backslashes. `"C:\Users\91888\Downloads\chromedriver_win32.exe"` should be `"C:\\Users\\91888\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32.exe"` in your source file so that the backslashes are preserved in the resulting String.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r " ' \ )
```

...implies that there was a compilation error in the escape sequence while interpreting the *ChromeDriver* absolute path.

Using Java while mentioning the system paths you need to escape the `\` character for the compiler to understand the path.

---

### Solution

You need to escape all the `\` characters, effectively replace all the `\` with `\\`. So the line of code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\Users\91888\Downloads\chromedriver_win32.exe");
```

needs to be:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\91888\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32.exe");
```